# Why is network stack ignoring icmp replies from non-default interface?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, icmp, mtr

I have following situation:

- eth0 - default gateway ( ip: 172.28.183.100, gw: 172.28.183.1 )
- eth0 - secondary network connection ( ip: 172.28.171.2, gw: 172.28.171.2).

routing looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.28.183.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.28.171.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
172.28.173.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
78.46.78.0      172.28.171.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         172.28.183.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

As you can see there is special route for 78.46.78.0/24 - this traffic should go by the secondary net eth2.

Which works. I can do any kind of tcp connections to machines in 78.46.78.0/24.

But, when I try to mtr them, I got weird result:

```
root@blob:~# mtr --report --report-cycles=5 78.46.78.198
HOST: blob                        Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1. 172.28.171.1                  0.0%     5    0.6   0.6   0.5   0.6   0.0
  2. ???                          100.0     5    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

In tcpdump output I see returned replies of time-to-live exceeded:

```
10:16:28.158888 IP 172.28.171.2 > 78.46.78.198: ICMP echo request, id 2092, seq 59520, length 44
10:16:28.159363 IP 172.28.171.1 > 172.28.171.2: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 72
10:16:28.259153 IP 172.28.171.2 > 78.46.78.198: ICMP echo request, id 2092, seq 59776, length 44
10:16:28.359546 IP 172.28.171.2 > 78.46.78.198: ICMP echo request, id 2092, seq 60032, length 44
10:16:28.408129 IP 10.9.208.1 > 172.28.171.2: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
10:16:28.428193 IP 10.9.208.2 > 172.28.171.2: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
10:16:28.459953 IP 172.28.171.2 > 78.46.78.198: ICMP echo request, id 2092, seq 60288, length 44
10:16:28.560260 IP 172.28.171.2 > 78.46.78.198: ICMP echo request, id 2092, seq 60544, length 44
10:16:28.618138 IP 10.9.213.6 > 172.28.171.2: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
10:16:28.660678 IP 172.28.171.2 > 78.46.78.198: ICMP echo request, id 2092, seq 60800, length 44
10:16:28.708130 IP 10.9.212.253 > 172.28.171.2: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
10:16:28.730193 IP 213.158.195.13 > 172.28.171.2: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
10:16:28.761086 IP 172.28.171.2 > 78.46.78.198: ICMP echo request, id 2092, seq 61056, length 44
10:16:28.861380 IP 172.28.171.2 > 78.46.78.198: ICMP echo request, id 2092, seq 61312, length 44
10:16:28.938167 IP 213.248.89.153 > 172.28.171.2: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
```

but, with strace on mtr i see that these ICMP replies are not delivered to mtr!

I think that the reason might be that the source ip of icmp response comes from "wrong" interface" - i.e. ICMP reply comes from (for example) 10.9.212.253 (some intermediary router), but this ip should be routed via eth0, while it comes to eth2.

Is it sensible reason? What can I do about it to make mtr work even to my "special" network?

iptables are set using:

```
iptables -P INPUT   DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT  ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo                                  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1                                -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp                                -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1                              -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A INPUT   -j LOG --log-prefix 'IPTABLES: '
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix 'IPTABLES: '
```

But I don't see any icmp-related packages with kern.log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Rafał Ramocki - solution is simple - you have to turn off rp_filter-ing on eth2 interface:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth2/rp_filter
```

From kernel docs:

```
rp_filter
---------

Integer value determines if a source validation should be made. 1 means yes, 0
means no.  Disabled by default, but local/broadcast address spoofing is always
on.

If you  set this to 1 on a router that is the only connection for a network to
the net,  it  will  prevent  spoofing  attacks  against your internal networks
(external addresses  can  still  be  spoofed), without the need for additional
firewall rules.
```

While nice for preventing spoofing attacks (at least some), it definitely kills some functionality if you have more internet connections.