# squid3 with tcp_outgoing_address could not connect to anywhere

Tags: iptables, squid, linux-networking, route

I have one server with 3 interfaces (3 physical lan card), which are connected to 3 different routers. Each router has a different subnet, i.e. the 3 interfaces of server belong to 3 different subdomains:

```
eth0    192.168.1.42 #default interface
eth1    192.168.11.42
eth2    192.168.12.42
```

I have installed a squid server on the server with minimal configuration, and it indeed works fine with web browser. Here is the squid.conf:

```
acl all src all
acl lan src 192.168.0.0/16
http_port 3128
access_log /var/log/squid3/access.log squid
hosts_file /etc/hosts
http_access allow lan
http_access deny all
```

Now, I would like the squid server to use one particular interface (eth1) instead of eth0 to send out the packets (because that router has openvpn inside). And after some research, I tried with the following:

```
tcp_outgoing_address 192.168.11.42
```

However, after this line is added, I could not go to ANY place from browser using the squid proxy. After some Googling, some mentioned about SNAT of iptables and ip route, but that seems really complicated, and I am really not sure what I should set in this case.

I tried with `squid3 -k debug`, but I only got something like this in cache.log, not sure if it helps:

```
2014/06/26 17:16:42.843| comm_calliocallback: 0
2014/06/26 17:16:42.843| event.cc(225) checkEvents
2014/06/26 17:16:42.853| EventDispatcher::dispatch: Running 'MaintainSwapSpace'
2014/06/26 17:16:42.853| storeMaintainSwapSpace: f=1.00, max_scan=500, max_remove=80
2014/06/26 17:16:42.853| UFSSwapDir::maintain: /var/spool/squid3 removed 0/80 f=1.0000 max_scan=500
2014/06/26 17:16:42.853| event.cc(315) schedule: Adding 'MaintainSwapSpace', in 1.00 seconds
2014/06/26 17:16:42.853| comm_iocallbackpending: 0
2014/06/26 17:16:42.853| comm_calliocallback: 0
2014/06/26 17:16:42.853| comm_calliocallback: 0
2014/06/26 17:16:42.863| comm_iocallbackpending: 0
2014/06/26 17:16:42.863| comm_calliocallback: 0
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some further research, I think the answer is `source plicy routing`.

I followed the steps here:

[Can't ping multihomed Linux machine on non-default interface](https://serverfault.com/questions/487891/cant-ping-multihoned-linux-machine-on-non-default-interface)

And it works like charm!